# I can't see class files

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to find where my class files are.

I'm executing:

```
D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\listenerTest\com\example>javac Dog.java Lis
tenerTester.java MyServletContextListener.java

D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\listenerTest\com\example>dir
 Volume in drive D is Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 181E-3406

 Directory of D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\listenerTest\com\example

04/22/2012  10:30 PM    <DIR>          .
04/22/2012  10:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/22/2012  10:12 PM                 0 Dog.java
04/22/2012  10:20 PM                 0 ListenerTester.java
04/22/2012  10:08 PM                20 MyServletContextListener.java
04/22/2012  10:31 PM               702 web.xml
               4 File(s)            722 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  590,213,869,568 bytes free

D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\listenerTest\com\example>
```

Can anyone help me find out where my class files are? Are they being compiled? Do they exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One class file is produced per class present (not per file).

As your two of your files are empty, and the third is nearly empty, I would surmise that your files do not contain any class declarations. The compiler, therefore, does not produce any class files.

Answer (score 0):

```
04/22/2012  10:12 PM                 0 Dog.java
04/22/2012  10:20 PM                 0 ListenerTester.java
04/22/2012  10:08 PM                20 MyServletContextListener.java
```

This shows that `Dog.java` and `ListenerTester.java` are EMPTY files. Not sure about the third one but its too small in size. Due to absence of code that can be used to create class files, you are not seeing any class files produced.

Add some valid java code to those files and compile. You will see class files being generated.